# Problema con la propiedad flex de css

Tags: html, css, flex

Tengo un problema con la propiedad `flex` en `css`: le estoy dando un valor de `justify-content: flex-start` para ordenar mis elementos HTML, el problema consiste en que ese número de elementos puede aumentar como disminuir, y cuando aumentan los elementos se van quedando los elementos cada vez más pequeños hasta deformarse mi maquetación.

¿Hay alguna forma de que una vez haya cierta cantidad de elementos, los demás elementos bajen a la segunda línea o segundo bloque?

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir tu código? Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo necesitas `flex-flow: wrap;`

```css
section{
  width: 100%;
  height: 170px;
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  align-items: start;
  padding: 5px;
  
}

div {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>Elemento</div>
  <div>Elemento</div>
  <div>Elemento</div>
  <div>Elemento</div>
  <div>Elemento</div>
  <div>Elemento</div>
  <div>Elemento</div>
  <div>Elemento</div>
  <div>Elemento</div>
</section>
```

Este lo que hace es decir como se van a componer los elementos hijos, puede ver mas sobre esto [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex-flow)

Comment: Me funciono! Me puedes explicar como funciona `flex-flow: wrap;` por favor.

Comment: Recuerda siempre agregar una explicación a tu código para que la calidad de tu aporte mejore y ayude a mas gente

Comment: Listo, editado un poco.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando agregas la propiedad `display` con valor `flex`, hay dos estilos que se definen por defecto: `flex-direction: row` y `flex-wrap: nowrap`. Lo único que debes hacer es **cambiar el valor** de la propiedad `flex-wrap` a `wrap` y asegurarte que el valor de`flex-direction` sea `row`.

Hay una propiedad *shortland* llamada `flex-flow`, en la que puedes unir valores tanto de `flex-direction` como de `flex-wrap`, de la siguiente forma: `flex-flow: row wrap`.

Te dejo un [sitio](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) que me ha ayudado a comprender el uso de la tecnología flexbox en CSS.

Comment: Falso: la propiedad `flex-direction` tiene como valor por defecto `row`, de hecho lo explican en el mismo sitio que consideras «buenísimo».

Comment: Tienes razón, rectifico mi respuesta.